# Extract a variable value in JavaScript code from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, regex

I'm getting the HTML code of a webpage using this parsing library called [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna). Basically the stripped down version looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in client-root">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window._sharedData = { 
            // Some JSON
        };
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Javascript code
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // More Javascript code
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

There are multiple `script` tags within the `body`. I want to access the one with the variable named `window._sharedData` and extract it's value which is a JSON dictionary.

I tried with using regular expressions but it's returning `nil`. Maybe something's wrong with my pattern?

```
if let doc = try? HTML(url: mixURL, encoding: .utf8), let body = doc.body, let htmlText = body.text {  

    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: htmlText.utf8.count)
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "/<script type=\"text/javascript\">window._sharedData = (.*)</script>/")
    let s = regex.firstMatch(in: htmlText, options: [], range: range)
    print(s)

}
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Remove the first and last `/` in the regex pattern. Add `(?s)` at the pattern start. Replace `.*` with `.*?`. Add `\\s*` before `window`. And escape the literal `.` See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/mI9XIv/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot! I tried your pattern. However I had to make a couple of changes because in Swift I had to escape the `\` like this `\\`. So the full pattern looks something like this `(?s)<script type=\"text/javascript\">\\s*window\\._sharedData = (.*?)</script>`. But somehow it doesn't match :/

Comment: Yes, to define a ``\`` you must use ``\\`` in a string literal. It is not a change to regex, it is just how you write that string in the Swift code. How come it does not? This is how it must look like: `pattern: "(?s)<script type=\"text/javascript\">\\s*window\\._sharedData = (.*?)</script>"`. If it does not work, the problem is with your code. Note that Swift regex works on UTF16 encoded strings. Try replacing `htmlText.utf8.count` with `htmlText.utf16.count`

Comment: Well, I have tried my initial suggestion and it returns `Optional(<_NSRegularExpressionNSTextCheckingResultResult: 0x00005582ba121120>)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. It does work when I try it with the html as a string like in my code above. But for some reason it doesn't when I'm doing it with the html code I get dynamically using that library. Let me share my [demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hnpd1s679ozs497/HTMLParserDemo.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to help you with this, the only "fishy-for-me" thing that I see is `.utf8` in `HTML(url: mixURL, encoding: .utf8)`, but I can't test the code.

Comment: It's alright. Thanks for your help so far :) I did change that to utf16 and the HTML returned a bunch of Chinese or Japanese characters!

Comment: Yeah, that always happens when you open an ANSI text with Russian settings in UTF16 encoding. It is corrupt, so, go back to UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
import Foundation
import Kanna

let htmlString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\" class=\"no-js not-logged-in client-root\"><head> <meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><body> <script type=\"text/javascript\"> window._sharedData = { \"string\": \"Hello World\" }; </script> <script type=\"text/javascript\"> </script> <script type=\"text/javascript\"> </script></body></html>"

guard let doc = try? HTML(html: htmlString, encoding: .utf8) else { print("Build DOM error"); exit(0) }

let body = doc.xpath("//script")
            .compactMap { $0.text }
            .filter { $0.contains("window._sharedData") }
            .map { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: " window._sharedData = ", with: "") }
            .map { $0.dropLast(2) }
            .first

print("body: ", body) 
// body:  Optional("{ \"string\": \"Hello World\" }")
```

After that you can check that body not nil and ready

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way to grab the value of `window._sharedData` variable? The JSON part only? That's where I'm stuck actually.

Comment: @Isuru Updated.

Comment: I'm trying it with the full HTML page (not the stripped down version shown in the question) and it still returns the complete block with the variable too. See in my [demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hnpd1s679ozs497/HTMLParserDemo.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Can you provide URL to page?

Comment: Also in what file you try to get result? (in ViewController I see some regexp code...)